# background animation zoom in and out slideshow in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, web

i am trying to create animated background slideshow that zoom in the first image and then come back to normal for the next image and zoom it, any ideas please ??

```
    .img-contaner {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     animation: img 20s ease-in-out infinite;
     background: url(./1.jpg);  
      }
      @keyframes img{
     25%{
         background: url(./2.jpg);
         transform: scale(1.2); 
     }
     50%{
         background: url(./3.jpg);
         transform: scale(1.2); 
     }
     75%{
         background: url(./4.jpg);
         transform: scale(1.2); 
     }
     100%{
         background: url(./1.jpg); 
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

     }
```

i tried this but the image stays zoomed the whole animation

Comment: @blex here you go: `<div class="img-contaner"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

- **Don't override** the background-image using the [`background:` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background). You'll override the other background-* styles.
- **Preload all your images** into the browser to prevent flickering using a `:before` pseudo
- It's *"container"* not *"contaner"*
- **Math time**:
  4 images + 4 transitions + 4 pauses = **12**. `100 / 12 = 8.3` Calculate incrementally and floor or round your value to be used as animation keyframes steps:

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

.img-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: center / cover no-repeat;
  animation: img 20s ease-in-out infinite;
}

/* Preload images to prevent flicker during animation */
.img-container:before {
  content: "";
  background-image:
    url(//placehold.it/500x300/0bf?text=1),
    url(//placehold.it/500x300/f0b?text=2),
    url(//placehold.it/500x300/bf0?text=3),
    url(//placehold.it/500x300/0fb?text=4);
}

@keyframes img {
  0%, 8% {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/500x300/0bf?text=1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  17% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  
  25%, 33% {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/500x300/f0b?text=2);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  41% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  
  50%, 58% {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/500x300/bf0?text=3);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  66% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  
  75%, 83% {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/500x300/0fb?text=4);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  91% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Comment: No it's not what i want but thanks for helping, [i solved](https://codepen.io/hmo0tah/pen/OJMgNwO?editors=1100)